# JS Script triggering on scroll of safari (Iphone X)

Tags: javascript

For some reason a JS script is only triggering once the user has scrolled a tiny bit, however it loads perfectly fine on desktop on page load.

Potential causes:

- WP Rocket JS optimisations? (UPDATE: Deactivated, issue persists)
- CDN Serving files?

Code:

```
window.onload = function () {
    $('div.wistia_responsive_padding').each(function() {
        var wistia = $(this);
        var actualHeight = $(this).children(".video-wrapper").height();
        var containerHeight = $(this).height();
        var currentMargin = 30;

        currentMargin = $(".marginFinder").height();

        var differentHeight = (actualHeight - containerHeight) + currentMargin;

        if(differentHeight < 0) {
            $(this).css("margin-bottom", differentHeight+"px");
        }

        $(window).resize(function () {
            actualHeight = wistia.children(".video-wrapper").height();
            containerHeight = wistia.height();
            currentMargin = $(".marginFinder").height();

            differentHeight = (actualHeight - containerHeight) + currentMargin;

            if(differentHeight < 0) {
                wistia.css("margin-bottom", differentHeight+"px");
            }
        });
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it was to do with a console error with jQuery functions being used without declaring "$", however, it was not showing up in my local version only on the staging server:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    window.onload = function() {
        $('div.wistia_responsive_padding').each(function() {
            var wistia = $(this);
            var actualHeight = $(this).children(".video-wrapper").height();
            var containerHeight = $(this).height();
            var currentMargin = 30;

            currentMargin = $(".marginFinder").height();

            var differentHeight = (actualHeight - containerHeight) + currentMargin;

            if(differentHeight < 0) {
                $(this).css("margin-bottom", differentHeight+"px");
            }

            $(window).resize(function () {
                actualHeight = wistia.children(".video-wrapper").height();
                containerHeight = wistia.height();
                currentMargin = $(".marginFinder").height();

                differentHeight = (actualHeight - containerHeight) + currentMargin;

                if(differentHeight < 0) {
                    wistia.css("margin-bottom", differentHeight+"px");
                }
            });
        });
    };
});
```